# MySQL Select Multiple in IF statment

Tags: mysql

I return a value if only one row matches my where condition,

```
SELECT IF((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UserWins WHERE Wins = (select max(Wins) from UserWins)) = 1, (SELECT UserId FROM UserWins WHERE Wins=(select max(Wins) from UserWins)), null)
```

This works fine as long as I only want to select one column, if I try to return more it fails with "Error #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s) in Mysql". I understand the error but I'm unsure what is the best way to do this,

I can summarise this down to

```
SELECT IF(TRUE, (SELECT UserId, Nick FROM UserWins), null)
```

Would appreciate any input.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve for?  Is it "Return columns from the `UserWins` table where the user has never won more than `1`?"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions here, I think what you are after is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM UserWins uw
WHERE EXISTS
  (
    SELECT 1
    FROM UserWins 
    WHERE uw.UserId = UserId
    GROUP BY UserId 
    HAVING MAX(Wins) = 1
      AND COUNT(*) = 1
  )
  AND Wins = 1;
```

This will pull back the `UserWins` record where the `UserId` for that record has only ever had a `1` in the `Win` column (no higher).

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish is to return the row with the highest entry of 'Wins' but only if there's 1 entry for that highest value. 
My original query does accomplish that but only if I want to return a single column, not the entire row/ multiple columns.

Comment: How do you determine a unique row in this table? Is there an ID or something?  Essentially that `Exists` can be turned into `WHERE <unique column> IN (SELECT <unique column>... ` type of correlated subquery and return what you are after. But without knowing how your table is structured, I can't guess what that column might be.

Comment: The UserId column is the primary key in this table. There can multiple entries with the same win count. You mentioning using subquery made me realise the following works, however it seems very verbose?

`SELECT * FROM UserWins WHERE UserId = IF((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UserWins WHERE Wins = (select max(Wins) from UserWins)) = 1, (SELECT UserId FROM UserWins WHERE Wins=(select max(Wins) from UserWins)), null)`

Comment: Check out my edit. I've added a couple of more conditions in there. In the correlated EXISTS subquery I've added to only allow records where the max(wins) is 1 AND the count of those `max(wins) = 1` is also 1. I've also added to the WHERE clause of the main statement to be that single record for the user where those two prior conditions are true. It should be, if I understand correctly, what you are after.